# Why was Rutherford wrong and Bohr was right (then)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, orbitals, models

I read that Rutherford was ruled out because he predicted that electrons revolve around the nucleus and Bohr stated that accelerating electrons emit electromagnetic radiation and should collide with the nucleus. He corrected it by showing that electrons revolve in stationary orbits. I don't know the quantum mechanics behind that. But I want to know the reason. Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

Rutherford's model of the atom was based on the scattering experiment undertaken by Geiger & Marsden and which resulted in the [Rutherford scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_scattering) cross-section. Essentially, it states that most projectiles travel through the target without any significant deflection, which further suggests that an atom is mostly empty, leading to the conclusion of a positive charge core (the nucleus), with negative charges (the electrons) in orbit around it. Interestingly enough, the exact same result of the Rutherford formula is predicted for Coulomb scattering within non-relativistic quantum mechanics.

However, what Rutherford's model was unable to describe were the discrete spectra of atoms, as for example the [Hydrogen spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series). If electrical charges were indeed in orbital motion around the nucleus in a classical sense, they would have to radiate energy continuously. This would not only result in a continuous spectrum as opposed to the observed sharp lines, but would also result in the atom collapsing in a time somewhere of the order of $10^{-9}$ seconds. Obviously, atoms are stable.

These discrepancies between observation and theoretical predictions were worked out by Bohr in the case of Hydrogen in what is historically known as the [Bohr model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model). It's a precursor to quantum mechanics which guesses some of the correct answers but fails to provide suitable and self-consistent explanations based on an axiomatic set. In essence, Bohr had to come up with a new kind of dynamics  that was different from the classical laws of mechanics and electromagnetism, but he couldn't justify these laws beyond the need to fit the experiment and nor could he connect them with established laws. This was later worked on, developed and eventually solved by many people including Bohr himself and Paul Dirac, whom I believe wrote the first ever rigorous treatise on the topic, [The Principles of Quantum Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Principles_of_Quantum_Mechanics). Mind you, by now the book is dated and fairly difficult to read, but it's still very much the most beautiful book ever written on the topic and it offers a clear look into many of the struggles and resolutions of early XXth century physics.

Comment: "which further suggests that an atom is mostly empty, leading to the conclusion of a positive charge core (the nucleus)" seems incorrect. The reason to say that positive charge core exist was due to deflection back of alpha particles . There were only 1 in 12000 particles approximately that appeared to rebound which shows that there is a positive core

Comment: "but would also result in the atom collapsing in a time somewhere of the order of 10−9 seconds."- How did they calculated the time? Did they know the kinetic energy of electrons in orbit? How did they find it?

Comment: @ArsenalCreation "How did they find it" they were good at planetary orbits ,   and by 1900 the mass and charge of the electron was known, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron#Discovery_of_free_electrons_outside_matter  Also classical bremsstrahlung  radiation mathematics were known. also in the previous comment , not really "incorrect" but not the main reason for the deduction.

Comment: @ArsenalCreation The Rutherford formula for the scattering cross section peaks in the forward direction, i.e. most particles passed through the foil without any significant deflection. Back-scattering was also observed, but the main point was that a scattering cross-section compatible with a continuous charge distribution was not observed.

As for your second question, you can look for example at the Larmor formula here:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/543433/radiative-collapse-of-a-classical-atom

Answer (score 0):

Both the Rutherford and the Bohr model of the atom treats electrons like classical particles which was proved to be wrong.But with the data of that time Bohr's model was correct and Rutherford's model was wrong because Bohr's model agreed with classical electromagnetism ,energy conservation and angular momentum conservation while Rutherford's model didnt.